# EASession OutputStream write size limit

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth, eaaccessory

I am trying to write to a MFi accessory over the protocol (bluetooth) supported by the accessory from my iOS application using the EASession OutputStream. The issue is that when the written data is more than approximately 3.8Kbytes, the packet is split. For eg. if the packet size to write is 5Kbytes, then the accessory receives the packet in two i.e. first packet of size 3.8Kbytes and second of size 1.2Kbytes.
So is there a size limit for writing data over EASession? If so is it configurable so that i can send bigger chunks of data?
Thanks,
TSJ

Comment: It's a *stream*.  Your protocol needs to include appropriate framing so that you can make sense of the data independent of any packet size limitations.

Comment: There is a frame (Serial Line IP packet) sent which the software on the accessory decodes it. But the frames itself is getting split before the software on the accessory receives it.

Comment: When working with streams your protocol has to be able to handle fragmentation. For example you could have a header that says "there will be 4096 bytes in this frame" followed by the 4096 bytes. Then you know how to reassemble the frame. It's the same thing you would need to do when working with a TCP connection.